# Doubts on Particle in a box model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I have following three doubts.

1. For a particle in a box problem, a particle is moving within a box of length a. The normalization constant is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$. My question is if we take a negative integer (i.e. value of quantum number as -1, -2, ...... etc), then it will give a different solution like $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}sin(\frac{\pi  x}{a})$. So, why are we not considering negative integers?
2. After normalizing the wave function of a particle in a box, the normalization constant can be a complex number like: $e^{(i\theta)}\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$. Why are we only considering real numbers?
3. The conditions of wave functions like continuous, normalizability, are these coming from postulates of quantum mechanics?

Comment: If the wavefunction isn’t normalized, then the probability of finding the particle somewhere isn’t 1. Would that make sense?

Comment: Have you learned how energy eigenstates evolve in time? Thinking about this should help you answer your questions about negative signs and complex phases.

Comment: The energy is identical for negative and positive solutions, and the phase of the wavefunction does not convey any physical information (aka it does not change the probability density). Therefore, the negative integer solutions are identical to the positive integer solutions, and are thus redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: General tip: Consider to only ask 1 question per post.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) and 2), we can ignore phases (including negative signs) as there is only one particle in the box. When we measure a particles position we do not measure $\phi(x)$ but we instead measure $|\phi(x)|^2$. So, if you wanted to, you could consider complex normalisation constants (including e.g. $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$ or $i\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$), but that solution is in a sense indifferent from the one with $\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$ as its constant (as all of these constants have the same magnitude of $\frac{2}{a}$)

However, when you have multi particle systems, you do indeed have to worry about the relative phases between particles.

For example, a system which contains two particles and has:
$\phi_1(x) = \phi_2(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\exp(\frac{\pi x i}{a})$ is indeed different to a system with e.g $\phi_1(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\exp(\frac{\pi xi}{a})$ and $\phi_2(x) = i\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\exp(\frac{\pi xi}{a})$. (Note however we could times both these wavefunctions by e.g. $i$ and the system would be "unchanged". It is only relative phases which matter.)

---

For 3), continuity is required as the particle has finite energy & momentum. The Hamiltonian is $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \hat{V} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \hat{V}$ and $\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. If the wavefunction was not continuous then the particle's momentum would be infinite, and if its derivative was not continuous then the particle would have infinite energy.